# Symfony console command alias for version 2 and 3+

Tags: bash, symfony, alias

when working a lot with Symfony on the console its nice to have alias for a short call of `php app/console`, so far I had: `alias c=php app/console`.

But from Symfony version 3 the console is now at bin/console. How can I create an alias which works regardless of the Symfony version of the directory I’m in? Because I work different projects versions.

I tried this but it doesn’t work with the commands you pass after to it...
`c='[[ -f bin/console ]] && php bin/console || php app/console'`

Danke,
Torsten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same need a while ago. You can use bash functions for this. In your case an example would be:

```
c()
{
    if [ -f bin/console ]; then
        php bin/console "$@"
    elif [ -f app/console ]; then
        php app/console "$@"
    else
        echo "No console found"
    fi
}
```

You define this in the same place as your alias before, like in your .bashrc. Make sure to remove your alias.

Answer (score 0):

In the [OhMyZsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) [Symfony plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/symfony2/symfony2.plugin.zsh), it's arranged (partly) as thus:

```
# plugins/symfony2/symfony2.plugin.zsh

_symfony_console () {
  echo "php $(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -name 'console' -type f | head -n 1)"
}


#Alias
alias sf='`_symfony_console`'
```